# Test is trying to load a type from its own assembly

Tags: c#, moq, xunit

I've got a test class that looks like:

```
// disclaimer: some type names have been changed to protect IP, 
// there may be inconsistencies

using Moq; 
using MyComp.MyProj.DataAccessLayer;

namespace Test.Common.Data.DataAccessLayer
{
    public class Test
    {
        Mock<IApplicationData> appData;
        Mock<IConfig> config;

        public Test()
        {
            this.appData = new Mock<IApplicationData>();
            this.config = new Mock<IConfig>();
        }


        [Fact]
        public void GetNewInstance_WithoutUser( )
        {
            this.config.Setup(c => c.GetConfigInt(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(1);
            // DalFactory is a type in MyComp.MyProj.DataAccessLayer
            var dal = DalFactory.GetDataAccessLayer(1, "fakestring", (IApplicationData)this.appData.Object, (IConfig)this.config.Object);
            Assert.IsType <IDataAccessLayer>(dal); 
        }
    }
}
```

```

The problem here is that whenever  it tries to access the `DalFactory` type, it throws this exception:

```
System.TypeLoadException : Could not load type 'MyComp.MyProj.DataAccessLayer.DalFactory' from assembly 'DataAccessLayer, Version=0.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

The Version is the key there, since the `MyComp.MyProj.DataAccessLayer` is in an assembly with Version 8.0.x while the test is in an assembly with Version 0.9.0 (or 1.0.0 or 0.0.1, I've tried several values).

Question is, why would Moq be trying to load the wrong assembly for this type?

I've tried: looking in the GAC to see if there's an assembly being loaded from there, re-adding the project references, changing AssemblyTitle in the test AssemblyInfo.cs, changing the name of the class the test is in and using an alias on the `using` statement. No effect.

The method for GetDataAccessLayer is a `public static` so I don't think `InternalsVisibleTo` factors in here. If I F12 navigate to the type being tested, it goes fine, gets to the right place.

If I put `Assert.True(1 == 1);` as the only thing in the Test method, it runs fine and passes.

What should I try next to fix this issue?

Comment: Side note: Your assembly is not signed, so version should not really matter. Check complete exception - you may be missing dependencies (or something like it).

Comment: Check what build profile you are using in project properties. Is is targetting correct .net version or client profile? Check the output directory of the project. How are you adding reference in this class?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1. re-build your code in *MyComp.MyProj.DataAccessLayer* project
2. re-build *Test* project
3. run tests again

see if that helps

Also make sure the client Target Framework is the same for both projects (Properties > Application > Target Framework)

Comment: None of those helped. Thanks though.